# Mongo View taking 28 seconds to load 945 documents(12 fields)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, bson

I created a mongoView to shorten time exhausted on querying the result in node.js but it's taking a lot of time to fetch it.
This is what a typical document is I'm trying to get from view.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("637612745905f665b1d4849d"),
    "clientName" : "Hirak Jyoti",
    "projectNumber" : "2260",
    "MATERIAL" : 7545.67,
    "PROCUREMENT" : NumberInt(823),
    "SERVICEORDER" : 786.02,
    "MATERIALTRANSFER" : 5152.35,
    "customerDesignSignOffDate" : ISODate("2022-11-16T18:45:33.168+0000"),
    "currentStage" : "Completed",
    "assignedDate" : ISODate("2022-11-17T11:11:19.198+0000"),
    "percentCompletion" : 89.60595944429058,
    "dateDifferenceInDays" : 281.84131481481484
}
```

**Now there is a bottleneck in reading the documents in studio3T, sending it to frontEnd is no fuss as it is around 2MB,  is there any way to shorten the time taken to read from db, like storing in a different format or serializing it, converting to binary for storage or anything goes really**

BTW I created this view from 6 collections, 5 lookups and total 20 stages if thats of relevance.

Edit- Removed image as someone suggested,
The collections have indexes on _id, and those fields too that are used in lookup in foreign collections.

***My question quickly wrapped up, Can I fetch all the data from a collection(=~ 2.5MB) in mongodb under a second given the condition I'm not running any query or any other operation, Just the whole collection that's all***

***I was wondering if the bottleneck is due to the type of data being read from db(BSON/JSON), if that can be converted and stored as binary or something different that can later be decoded/parsed in the application(node/react)***

Comment: Please provide the query. 5 `$lookup` is rather much, NoSQL databases are not optimized for joins. Most likely you have a poor database design. What are your indexes?

Comment: Unless you've used `$merge` or otherwise persisted the data, then the view you are reading from is non-materialized. This is just a fancy way of saying that the aggregation in your view definition gets executed dynamically when you read from it. In terms of performance and amount of work the database has to do to gather the results, this is the same as having the client send the aggregation pipeline directly.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Hey, even if i read a collection instead of a view created from a complex query, the same bottleneck of reading time from db persists.

Comment: @user20042973 Hey, thanks for the info, do you know where can i read more on this, also is there any way to create an output view with pre-queried results such that when ever a parameter is changed(eg here if a date is changed in from a lookup collection, the view also gets updated)